# How can I get the file names from a folder in my web? (with JS)

Tags: javascript, html, file

I have a folder charged into my site that contains 120 images svg. I want to iterate over all them and get the name (or the URL) to put them in a list, then the user select one img and he can get the url.

I don't find what's the way to do it, is it possible in javascript vanilla?

Comment: By default, JavaScript does not have access to the file system. You would need a custom component (server-side code) to do this.

Comment: The browser cannot read the server's file system if that's what you mean. You either need the server to provide that information as part of the page or a script or an accessible endpoint, or a build tool that bundles that together before you deploy.

Comment: Thank you for the answers guys! I will search a solution by that way =)